# How to dismiss a java class in android

Tags: android

Hi guys i m from an iPhone background and new to android..i ve got two exitText fields and a button in xml layout,connected to the class AddKeyWord.when i click the button i wanted to dismiss my java class..is it possible.i don't want click the back button to go to my previous view.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addkeyword);
    btnCreate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

       public void onClick(View v) {

    });

      }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your java class is a activity, use ActivityName.this.finish()

Comment: yup mine is activity..k will give a try

Answer (score 1):

Just add finish() to your onClick method

Answer (score 1):

As there is onCreate(..) method so i am sure it is an activity, so you can use the following to finish this activity

```
btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

       public void onClick(View v) {
       AddKeyWord.this.finish();
    });

      }
      }
```

HTH :)

Answer (score 1):

Use finish() method. But if your previous activity is finished too than you should restart it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OldActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks guys for the effort...adding finish() totally worked...have a query...is there any delegation in android similar to iPhone

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781751/android-anything-similar-to-the-iphone-sdk-delegate-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

on click event call the new activity of your next page

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (arg0 == buttonSubmit) 
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextPage.class));
            }

});
```

in the next page

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (arg0 == backButton) 
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrevPage.class));
            }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent Nextpage= new Intent(ClassName.this,NextClassName.class);
            this.finish();
            startActivity(Nextpage);                
        }});
```